# MariaDB service stopped very often

Tags: database, service, crash, mariadb

MariaDB Server shutdonw anytime and it don

I reinstalled Mariadb server. I do some changed in my.cnf file. I reboot all server several times.

this is my log when it stop:

```
190718 08:58:09 mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0
190718 08:58:47 mysqld_safe mysqld restarted
190718  9:01:58 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.60-MariaDB) starting as process 6969 ...
190718  9:02:01 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
190718  9:02:01 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
190718  9:02:01 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
190718  9:02:01 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
190718  9:02:02 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 13.0M
190718  9:02:02 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
190718  9:02:05 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match
InnoDB: the log sequence number in the ib_logfiles!
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite buffer...
190718 09:03:15 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid ended
```

Comment: That log looks like after it started.

Answer (score 0):

That's a very old version of MariaDB that you are using :) the latest one is already 10.4.x

I would highly recommend upgrading to the latest.

But if due to some reason, an upgrade is not a possibility, please share my.cnf/server.cnf file contents, your OS version, available RAM on the server would also help.

Cheers,
Faisal.

Answer (score 0):

My VPS have 2Go physical memory

server.cnf here:

```
#
# These groups are read by MariaDB server.
# Use it for options that only the server (but not clients) should see
#
# See the examples of server my.cnf files in /usr/share/mysql/
#

# this is read by the standalone daemon and embedded servers
[server]

# this is only for the mysqld standalone daemon
[mysqld]

# this is only for embedded server
[embedded]

# This group is only read by MariaDB-5.5 servers.
# If you use the same .cnf file for MariaDB of different versions,
# use this group for options that older servers don't understand
[mysqld-5.5]

# These two groups are only read by MariaDB servers, not by MySQL.
# If you use the same .cnf file for MySQL and MariaDB,
# you can put MariaDB-only options here
[mariadb]

[mariadb-5.5]
```

my.cnf here:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
# Settings user and group are ignored when systemd is used.
# If you need to run mysqld under a different user or group,
# customize your systemd unit file for mariadb according to the
# instructions in http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log
pid-file=/var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid

#
# include all files from the config directory
#
!includedir /etc/my.cnf.d
```

thank for help

Comment: This looks like the very minimum config, I don't see anything here that can cause a crash. Can you share the crash log that shows the crash and some events before and after it?